# Changing default Django site name and domain from example.com to the proper ones

Tags: django, django-models, django-sites

According to the Django documentation ([here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework)):

> django.contrib.sites registers a post_migrate signal handler which
> creates a default site named example.com with the domain example.com.
> This site will also be created after Django creates the test database.
> To set the correct name and domain for your project, you can use a
> data migration.

Isn't it safe to directly change the default values from the Django admin panel? why?

Comment: I just change the default site object to the correct information when setting up a site.

Comment: thank you @markwalker_, our website has worked for years and I'm not sure whether it's safe to just change those values or not. there are many relations in our database too.

Comment: actually, my knowledge doesn't have any doubt here, but the official document made me confused.

Comment: You'll be fine to just edit the default site. It gets used by various things internally. Things like the "view on site" button which you may have seen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my answer.
First option is to change them on Django Admin site.
Second option is to create a migration file manually and run your migrations.
Let me describe the second option here.
Firstly, create an empty migration using following command.

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations --empty --name update_site_name app_name
```

Next, refer to this [blog](https://craiga.id.au/2020/05/26/rename-django-default-site) to edit the migration file.

Finally, run your migrations.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I changed the site_name directly in my database. I realized that a site can have a migration to define a default site_name from scratch, but for a case like mine in which there are a lot of data it's not necessary to add a migration. In other words, you should add a migration when you are developing your site, not when it's on the production stage.

Thanks to @markwalker for his comment